# Why are HTML links not loading until audio file has been played

Tags: javascript, html, audio, hyperlink

I am coding a website that has a navigation bar at the top of the page, containing normal, generic HTML5 link elements (using the "a" element):

```
<table id="menuButtonTable">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="/home" class="menuButton">
            Home
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="/play" class="menuButton">
            Play
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="/help" class="menuButton">
            Help
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="/contacts" class="menuButton">
            Contacts
         </a>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I also am loading multiple audio files in javascript:

```
const masterVolume = 0.4;
const breakingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/breaking.mp3");
breakingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const buildingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/building.mp3");
buildingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const choppingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/chopping.mp3");
choppingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const diggingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/digging.mp3");
diggingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const diggingSong = new Audio("Sound-Effects/digging-song.mp3");
diggingSong.volume = masterVolume;
const drinkingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/drinking.mp3");
drinkingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const eatingSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/eating.mp3");
eatingSound.volume = masterVolume;
const footstepSound1 = new Audio("Sound-Effects/footstep-1.mp3");
footstepSound1.volume = masterVolume;
const footstepSound2 = new Audio("Sound-Effects/footstep-2.mp3");
footstepSound2.volume = masterVolume;
const jazzSong = new Audio("Sound-Effects/jazz-song.mp3");
jazzSong.volume = masterVolume;
const leavesSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/leaves.mp3");
leavesSound.volume = masterVolume;
const themeSong = new Audio("Sound-Effects/oxygen-theme-song.mp3");
themeSong.volume = masterVolume;
const themeSong2 = new Audio("Sound-Effects/oxygen-theme-song-2.mp3");
themeSong2.volume = masterVolume;
const rainSong = new Audio("Sound-Effects/rain-song.mp3");
rainSong.volume = masterVolume;
const rainSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/rain.mp3");
rainSound.volume = masterVolume;
const waterSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/water.mp3");
waterSound.volume = masterVolume;
const windSound = new Audio("Sound-Effects/wind.mp3");
windSound.volume = masterVolume;
```

For some reason, whenever I click on one of the links at the top of the page, they never load and I am just left with the swirling circle, showing that the page is trying to load, at the top left. However, the links do load after the audio 'windSound' has been played. I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, does anyone know how to fix this strange problem?

Thanks

- primecubed

Comment: You're not providing enough information here - what's the _"swirling circle"_ you're talking about? How are the audio elements played? Please provide a [mcve] of the issue you're facing such that we can help you.

Comment: I am using chrome, and whenever a page is loading, there is a circle that rotates at the top left, indicating that a page is loading. And I am playing these audio objects using the .play method, for example 'waterSound.play();'

Comment: And how are you binding the links to the audio?

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that it is this way of setting the src that is causing the problem, which will not occur when the audio's src is hardcoded on the page in a conventional manner.

And my question is whether there is a better way to dynamically set the source for the audio player, given the page structure as described.

Comment: Thanks for your comment mate! I would have thought something like this as well, but before I added the wind sound the links working fine! It's really strange!